# JQuery not working with ListView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

So basically I have a couple of textboxes which I would only like to accept numbers in them however I cannot get the JQuery Im using below to work with a textbox inside a ListView nor with another asp.net page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>").keydown(function (event) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This code works with a normal textbox called txtSearch but when I insert txtQty insead of txtSearch it does not work :s

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvProducts" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lbProducts_ItemCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lvProducts_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="productoutercontainer">
                <div id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></div>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="productinnercontainer">
                <img class="pics" src="<%#Eval("ProductImage") %>" alt="<%#Eval("ProductName") %>" title="<%#Eval("ProductName") %>" />  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<% # Eval("ProductName") %>' Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                Quantity: <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" columns="3"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server"  Text="Add To Cart" CssClass="button2"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId")%>' OnClick="btnAddToCart_Click" />  <br /><br /><br />
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each textbox in the listview will have a different client **id**. Run the code and look at the generated client code by doing **view source** on your browser. Check the ids of **txtQty** textboxes.

1. Give txtQty a **CssClass**. Just give a name no need for css coding. Let say:

   ```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" CssClass="qty" runat="server" columns="3"/>
   ```
2. Change this:

   ```
   $("#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>")
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   $(".qty")
   ```

Now it has to work...

Comment: small question, how can I get the same code to work with a normal asp.net textbox which is inside a fieldset cause I tried doing it the same way but it did not work. Cheers